# Using VMware shared folders

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware

I have host `Win 8` that runs `WinXP` `WMVare` machine. I would like to have easy copy files from one machine to another and prefer not use network. Under `WMVare` options I found `Shared Folders` setup. I have enabled sharing one of host folders (assume `c:\blabla\`) there. But whats next? How to use it?

Comment: Install Guest Additions and navigate to the path which you have used for Guest, Reboot might be necessary.

Comment: VMWare Shared Folders uses a virtual network anyway, so it isn't *hugely* different.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the guest additions which can be done by clicking on the cd icon and then 'Insert guest additions'.

Once you finish the setup, reboot your computer and go into the settings of the virtual machine and setup shared folders. Once this will be one you should have a network location in your XP that attaches the folder on the 8.1